# How to print std::string array with printf in c++?

Tags: c++, string, printf, std, stdstring

I am trying to print std::string with printf and this my code. But it does not print the string I assigned.

Header File

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

#include <iostream>

class Cards : public cocos2d::CCLayer{
public:
    virtual bool init();
    virtual void load();

    std::string TotalCards[52];
}



#include "Cards.h"
    bool Cards::init(){
        if ( !CCLayer::init() ) {
            return false;
        }

        TotalCards[0] = "ClubsA";
        TotalCards[1] = "HeartsB";
        TotalCards[2] = "Diamonds4";

        return true;
    }


    void Cards::load(){

        printf("Hey I am HERE\n");

        for (int i=0 ; i<3; i++) {
            printf("CARD NAME %s\n", TotalCards[i].c_str());
        }
```

it prints just

CARD NAME

CARD NAME

CARD NAME

Comment: I don't believe that's your actual code.

Comment: I think you have missed some part of the code could you please post more??

Comment: Why have you indented every line of your question with `>` when you're not quoting anyone? Please add valid code to reproduce your problem and reformat the question.

Comment: yes this is my code, whats wrong in it?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is wrong is that what you are doing should work.

Comment: ok sorry let me edit it

Comment: What's wrong with it: you didn't `#include <string>` and you didn't declare `main`, so that can't be what you're compiling. **Show the actual code**

Comment: @Rafi Nothing is / seems to be wrong with the code, that is why your question is wrong =)

Comment: did u tried using #include<cstdio> ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that prints the strings. You probably is falling to initialize the string (`Cards::init()` not being called). Please post a **compilable** piece of code that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks @GuilhermeBernal this was the problem.

Comment: I am not used to with stachoverflow so sorry i you have problem with my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `Cards::init()` is called *and returns true* before calling `Cards::load`. The array accessed by `Cards::load` will consist of three empty strings in case `Cards::init()` is not called, or if it returns false.

Comment: Thanks @Frerich, this was the problem I was struggling with. The init method was not called so I assigned the values in the load() method. And now everything working fine, its printing the values.